# Uploaded form file gets deleted after HttpResponse is returned

Tags: django, asynchronous, django-forms, python-multithreading

I am saving the CSV file to text file using the handle_uploaded_file asynchronously using multithreading but the file argument passed to the function gets closed once the home function returns an HTTP response. I don't want to save the file and use it from that location but want to use it while it is available in memory.

ValueError: Seeking closed file

```
def handle_uploaded_file(f):
    destination =  open('name.txt', 'ab+')
    for chunk in f.chunks():
        destination.write(chunk)
    destination.close()

def home(request):
    if request.method=="POST":
        file = UploadForm(request.POST, request.FILES)
        if file.is_valid():
            g = request.FILES.dict()
            File = g['file']
            print(File)
            uploader_thread = Thread(target=handle_uploaded_file, args=[File])
            uploader_thread.start()
            file.save()
            return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('imageupload'))
    else:
        file=UploadForm()
    files=Upload.objects.all().order_by('-upload_date')
    return render(request,'home.html',{'form':file}) #,'files':files})
```

Answer (score 0):

Try like this.

```
import copy
def upload_handler(inmemory_file):
    with open(inmemory_file.name, 'wb+') as destination:
        for chunk in inmemory_file.chunks():
            destination.write(chunk)

def home(request):
    if request.method=="POST":
        file = UploadForm(data=request.POST, files=request.FILES)
        if file.is_valid():
            memory_file = copy.deepcopy(request.FILES['file'])
            upload_thread = Thread(target=upload_handler, args=(memory_file,))
            upload_thread.start()
            file.save()
            return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('imageupload'))
    else:
        file=UploadForm()
    files=Upload.objects.all().order_by('-upload_date')
    return render(request,'home.html',{'form':file}) #,'files':files})
```

Comment: It's not working. I'm still getting the     data = self.read(chunk_size)
ValueError: read of closed file   error.

Comment: I updated answer, use context manager. it works for me. strange.

Comment: I won't work for large files because while the one thread is processing the uploaded file, a response is returned and so the upload_handler cannot find the uploaded file anymore. That is the real problem. See if you can help with that.

Comment: I updated my answer, Please check last code. I am quiet busy now, If it does not work let me know and see later.

Comment: It's not possible to work on the uploaded file without file. I am trying windows backgroundUploader class to upload file in background and process it from there.

Comment: I am on linux and it works perfectly. Good luck in your job.